# Plot line connecting the medians of different boxplots

Tags: pgfplots, boxplot

I have a plot including multiple boxplots, grouped (5 by 5) in different conditions, as shown in the figure

[image]

Each group of 5 boxplots is based on data defined in a single file.
I'd like to add a line connecting the medians of each group of boxplots; something like this

[image]

This is a dummy subset of my dataset, which is larger. Therefore I'd like to rely on a way that doesn't require me directly inputting the different medians, but calculates them based on the files used to draw the boxplots.
Is there an easy way to do that? 
It would be a plus if I could decide how many boxplots to connect, e.g. only the first three of each group of five as opposed to all the five of them.

Here's the MWE used to generate the first figure

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\begin{filecontents}{audio1.tsv}
37  22  79  3   100
9   60  113 1   97
29  63  65  0   99
12  21  83  0   99
7   28  78  1   97
29  -10 73  1   98
17  32  73  1   98
10  58  78  0   95
17  45  73  2   99
38  28  91  0   96
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{speech4.tsv}
17  47  97  0   95
3   53  103 1   97
37  70  104 1   99
21  41  109 0   100
36  53  86  3   98
37  58  90  3   99
8   30  81  1   97
19  44  99  4   96
20  20  118 3   96
27  2   107 3   99
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{music3.tsv}
26  -5  79  4   100
12  61  101 0   99
13  32  116 1   98
10  17  94  3   93
9   81  75  4   100
7   50  58  0   98
30  56  79  2   99
19  28  93  1   92
10  31  49  1   99
11  22  46  0   100
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        groupplots,
        statistics,
    }
    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{%
        {color=red},
        {color=green},
        {color=blue},
        {color=magenta},
        {color=black}
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.10,
        width=8cm,
        height=5cm,
        cycle list name=mycolorlist,
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 2,
        },
        xmin=0,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={3,10,17},
        xticklabels={a,b,c},
        xlabel={something-x},
        ylabel={something-y},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
        % add here another variable so we can use it for calculations
        \foreach \filename/\j in {
            audio1/1,
            speech4/2,
            music3/3%
        } {
            \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
                % draw each originally row, now column as boxplot
                \addplot+ [
                    boxplot={
                        % now calculate the positions depending on how they
                        % should be organized
                        draw position=7*(\j-1) + \i+1,
                    }
                ] table [y index=\i] {\filename.tsv};
            }
        }
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slightly roundabout way of doing this, so there might well be more elegant solutions.

I create named coordinates at the middle of the median line, and use a normal `\draw` outside the `groupplot` to draw the line between medians. To only connect the first three in each group, change `{1,...,4}` to `{1,...,2}`.

[image: output of code]

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\begin{filecontents}{audio1.tsv}
37  22  79  3   100
9   60  113 1   97
29  63  65  0   99
12  21  83  0   99
7   28  78  1   97
29  -10 73  1   98
17  32  73  1   98
10  58  78  0   95
17  45  73  2   99
38  28  91  0   96
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{speech4.tsv}
17  47  97  0   95
3   53  103 1   97
37  70  104 1   99
21  41  109 0   100
36  53  86  3   98
37  58  90  3   99
8   30  81  1   97
19  44  99  4   96
20  20  118 3   96
27  2   107 3   99
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{music3.tsv}
26  -5  79  4   100
12  61  101 0   99
13  32  116 1   98
10  17  94  3   93
9   81  75  4   100
7   50  58  0   98
30  56  79  2   99
19  28  93  1   92
10  31  49  1   99
11  22  46  0   100
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
%\usetikzlibrary{
    \usepgfplotslibrary{
        groupplots,
        statistics,
    }
    \pgfplotscreateplotcyclelist{mycolorlist}{%
        {color=red},
        {color=green},
        {color=blue},
        {color=magenta},
        {color=black}
    }
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.10,
        width=8cm,
        height=5cm,
        cycle list name=mycolorlist,
        boxplot/draw direction=y,
    }
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[
        group style={
            group size=1 by 2,
        },
        xmin=0,
        xmax=20,
        xtick={3,10,17},
        xticklabels={a,b,c},
        xlabel={something-x},
        ylabel={something-y},
    ]
    \nextgroupplot
        % add here another variable so we can use it for calculations
        \foreach[count=\j] \filename in {
            audio1,
            speech4,
            music3%
        } {
            \foreach \i in {0,...,4} {
                % draw each originally row, now column as boxplot
                \addplot+ [
                    boxplot={
                        % now calculate the positions depending on how they
                        % should be organized
                        draw position=7*(\j-1) + \i+1,
                    }
                ] table [y index=\i] {\filename.tsv}
                 node (tmp)  at (boxplot box cs:\boxplotvalue{median},0.5) {}
                 ;
             \edef\tmp{\noexpand\coordinate (m-\j-\i) at (tmp.center);}
             \tmp
            }
        }
    \end{groupplot}

\foreach \j in {1,2,3}
  \draw [thick] (m-\j-0) foreach \i in {1,...,4} { -- (m-\j-\i) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works very well for me. Given that my final plot has more subplots, I had to change a small thing.
Namely, I added a way to distinguish the set of coordinates for each subplot using something like `\coordinate (mA-\j-\i) at (tmp.center);`, `\coordinate (mB-\j-\i) at (tmp.center);` etc...